# Spring MVC equivalent for Struts2 optiontransferselect

Tags: spring-mvc, struts2

Struts2 provides a wonderful UI component called "optiontransferselect" which is used to select/move options from one listBox to another.

Pls click here to check out this component:
http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2uitags/optiontransferselect-tag.shtml

Do we have a Spring-MVC equivalent for this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Spring doesn't contain any custom components. The only tags it has adds data binding to the existing JSTL tags. You can use [Struts with Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#struts) though.